# Why does my javascript not work when I remove carriage returns?

Tags: javascript, html

Working javascript example is as follows...

```
<script>var count=1; function setColor(button) { var property = document.getElementById(button); if (count == 0) {property.style.color="red"
 count=1;}else{property.style.color="green"
 count=0;}}</script>
```

Broken javascript example is as follows...

```
<script>var count=1; function setColor(button) { var property = document.getElementById(button); if (count == 0) {property.style.color="red" count=1;}else{property.style.color="green" count=0;}}</script>
```

The html...

```
<a href="#" id="button" style= "color:red" onclick="setColor('button'); playlist.toggleShuffle();">SHUFFLE</a>
```

Any help understanding this would be great.

Comment: I good example of why ASI is best avoided, it's not just personal preference.  Luckly, most minifier's will spot this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`property.style.color="red" count=1;` and `property.style.color="green" count=0;` are both not valid JavaScript. When you're not using carriage returns, you need a semicolon to delineate the end of the line after `"red"` and `"green"`.

What you're looking for is more like:

```
<script>var count=1; function setColor(button) { var property = document.getElementById(button); if (count == 0) {property.style.color="red"; count=1;}else{property.style.color="green"; count=0;}}</script>
```

This feature is referred to as semicolon insertion; you can read more about it at [this link](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).

... however I'm really not sure why you'd want to do this, as this saves maybe a byte or two here and there and offers no performance benefit, while nuking most of the readability of your code.

Comment: Not sure why you got a down-vote for this answer.  Up-voted to counter the no reason down-voter..

Comment: I knew it had to be something really simple! thanks, It was basically an exercise in why wont this work. No other real reason. Thanks